# Achieving smooth scroll with recyclerview android design library

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I wish to achieve following smooth with android layout without having to implement custom linear layout manager. My question is following achievable with just combination of android design library and nestedscrollview.

```
<ParentLayout>
Textview 
Imageview 
Gallery(viewpager)
Recyclerview
Textarea
Textview
Textview
</ParentLayout>
```

I wish to achieve smooth scroll throughout the parentlayout. if i am at last element of the recyclview the scroll should continue to parentlayout. How can this be achieved and which parentlayout should be used?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your needs, you don't need a nested nestedscrollview.  Just place your recyclerview inside of a parent scrollview and you should be good to go

If you provide a code sample or a wireframe of what you want to achieve, it'll be easier to help :)

Comment: Have edited the question to incorporate wireframe needed.. Also simply including scrollview will prevent the recyclerview to populate which will only get fixed if custom layout manager is implemented.